# the degree of field extension by $G$ and the order of $G$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let $L$ be $\mathbb{C}(x,y,z)$, the rational functions field over $\mathbb{C}$. $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are field isomorphisms of $L$ and defined as 
$$\sigma(x)=y,\sigma(y)=z,\sigma(z)=x$$
$$\tau(x)=x,\tau(y)=\omega y,\tau(z)=\omega^2 z$$
where $\omega$ is the $3$rd primitive root of unit. Let $M$ be the fixed field by $G=<\sigma,\tau$>. I want to find the degree of the extension $L/M$.

First the degree of extension $L/M$ be equal to the order of $G$. Because the order of $G$ is $27$ (by GAP), the degree of the extension of $L/M$ is $27$.

On the other hand, $x,y,z$ is the roots of the equation 
$$t^9-(x^3+y^3+z^3)t^6+(x^3y^3+y^3z^3+z^3x^3)t^3-x^3y^3z^3=0$$
So $[L:M]=[\mathbb{C}(x,y,z):M]\leq 9$.

Where am I make mistakes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$f(t) = t^9-(x^3+y^3+z^3)t^6+(x^3y^3+y^3z^3+z^3x^3)t^3-x^3y^3z^3 \in M[t]$$
then $L$ is the splitting field of $f(t)$ over $M$. However, this does not tell us anything about the degree of the splitting field except $[L:M] \leq 9!$

For example, you can recall that a cubic can have degree 6 as splitting field, and a quartic can have degree 24 as splitting field.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understood. Then how can I find the degree of $L/K$ by myself?  I wonder finding the order of $G$ is the only  way to find the degree.

Comment: I prefer computing the group order, although cumbersome. Label $\omega^i x_j$ by number 1-9, where $x=x_1, y=x_2, z=x_3$. Then $G$ is a permutation group generated by $(1 2 3)(4 5 6)(7 8 9)$ and $(2 5 8)(3 9 6)$. This way is more systematic.